# Error displaying "text" in php before calculating the operation

Tags: php, text, echo, display, calculation

I want to print out a text before printing the output of the calculation, without storing the text in a variable. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
$x = 5;
$y = 10.5;
  echo "add: 5+6 =" . $x + $y;
```

Comment: You should display all errors and warnings to see what is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1

Comment: Improved the answer with some explanations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code calculate addition $x + $y, then convert to string, then concatenate to string "add: 5+6=" (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php)

```
$x = 5;
$y = 10.5;
echo "add: 5+6 = ". strval($x + $y);
```

**About your code**

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php : concatenation operators have higher precedence than arithmetic operators.

Your original code is the same as:

```
$x = 5;
$y = 10.5;
echo (int)("add: 5+6 =" . $x) + $y;
```

That means: first, concatenate string "add: 5+6 =" . $x

```
add 5+6 =5
```

then cast to int (that return 0)

```
(int)("add: 5+6 =5")
```

then add $y

```
0 + 10.5
```

then echo it

```
echo 10.5;
```

So this is why your code return 10.5

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$x = 5;
$y = 10.5;

echo "add: 5+6 =" . ($x + $y); // automatic converts to `string`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<?php
    $x = 5;
    $y = 10.5;
    $z = $x + $y;
    echo "add: 5+6 = " . $z;
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $x = 5;
  $y = 10.5;
  printf("add: 5+6 = %f", $x + $y);
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$x = 5;
$y = 10.5;
$z=$x+$y;
echo "add:5+6 =".$z;
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it by concatinating your variable**

```
<?php
$x = 5;
$y =10.5;
$z=$x+$y;

echo "add: ".$x."+".$y." = ". $z;
?>
```

### output

```
add: 5+10.5 = 15.5
```